# Make javascript variable equal to input checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, input

Imagine I have an input like so:

```
<input id="submitCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="recieveEmails">
```

And some form of submit button, say;

```
<button id="submit" type="button" onclick="submit()"></button>
```

And Javascript like so:

```
function submit() {
    var newVar = document.getElementById("submitCheckbox");
}
```

And by using something like this, `newVar` would be equal to `True` or `False` depending on the status of the checkbox when the submit button is pressed?

PS. The Javascript example I provided is theoretical. Please don't rip into me because it "doesn't work"

Comment: You'd have to get the state with `document.getElementById("submitCheckbox").checked`

Comment: `var newVar = document.getElementById("submitCheckbox").checked;`

Comment: This would provide a boolean result? @adeneo

Comment: Thanks all. .Checked works great

Answer (score 1):

Use this **document.getElementById("submitCheckbox").checked** instead of **document.getElementById("submitCheckbox")** as shown here:

```js
function submit() {
    var newVar = document.getElementById("submitCheckbox").checked;
    console.log(newVar);
}
```

```html
<input id="submitCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="recieveEmails">
<br>
<button id="submit" type="button" onclick="submit()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Manish. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can

Comment: welcome Caspar!